# Is it grammatical correct to say: "x-year-ago ex-something"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Example sentence:

> She's my one-year-ago ex-girlfriend.

Is this grammatical? If not, what's a better option?

Comment: She was my girlfriend until a year ago?

Comment: She was my ex-girlfriend a year before.

Comment: That's wholly understandable and if we had 37 hours it might arguably be grammatically right or wrong.

Given that the phrase is going to crop up maybe two or three times in your whole life - one-year-ago; two-year-ago; three-year-ago… bored… why on Earth would you care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use "as of":

> She's my ex-girlfriend as of one year ago

where "as of [time]" means "from [time] onwards".